# How to download files from Google Drive synchronously?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, synchronous

Or is there a way to produce the same effect, i.e. the JavaScript program stopping until the download is complete (not using `setTimeout`)?

Comment: This is the wrong solution. Your js program should handle asynchronicity.

Comment: Asynchronous functions like the ones of this API take callbacks, that is function called after the operation has been done. You must put the sequel of your code in the callback. See the examples in the doc.

Comment: Thanks dystroy and Herms! We will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is asynchronous, so you need to handle the download asynchronously.  This is mainly because javascript runs single threaded and that's generally shared with the UI thread, so if you blocked your code on a download the user wouldn't be able to interact with the page at all until your code finished.

However, handling it asynchronously shouldn't be difficult, so long as the mechanism you're using to download the file supports a callback when it's done (which most should).

Say you had the following code:

```
function doDownload(url) {
  doSomeInitialStuff();
  startDownload(url);  // assuming this would block, which it can't
  doSomeOtherStuff();
  doMoreOtherStuff();
}
```

If your download mechanism supports a callback when it's done (a function that's called after the download is complete or has failed), then you would restructure your code like so:

```
function doDownload(url) {
  doSomeInitialStuff();
  startDownload(url, onDownloadComplete);
}

function onDownloadComplete() {
  doSomeOtherStuff();
  doMoreOtherStuff();
}
```

The specifics of how you callback works (args passed to it, how it's provided to the download code) will vary depending on the js libraries you're using, but this is the basic idea for how to handle it asynchronously.